# Counting boolean values based on certain conditions

Tags: sql-server, boolean, counting

[image: Database Table]

Dear All, Attached is the sql server 2016 database table. I want to get counts of column IsAssetIssued for true and flase values based on the condition AssetTypeID. I am trying

```
SELECT COUNT(IsAssetIssued) AS AvlAssets 
FROM AssetStatus 
WHERE (IsAssetIssued = True) 
  AND (AssetTypeID = 1)
```

but this is does not providing exact result for false values in the column. Please suggest a better solution.

Thanks,

Comment: What is your expected result ?. `True` in `Where` clause should be enclosed with *single quotes*

Comment: You are explicitly filtering out `False` values in your `WHERE` clause. So you won't ever get results relating to those rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
SELECT COUNT(IsAssetIssued) AS AvlAssets ,IsAssetIssued
FROM AssetStatus 
WHERE (AssetTypeID = 1)
group by IsAssetIssued
```

Comment: dear sir .. this statement is not counting the values i.e. true or false or 1 or 0 based on a criteria of AssetTypeID. What I want to do is to count IsAssetIssued column values i.e. true or false or 1 or 0 for a where condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT AssetTypeID,IsAssetIssued FROM 
(
SELECT AssetTypeID,IsAssetIssued,
COUNT(IsAssetIssued) OVER(Partition by AssetTypeID Order by AssetTypeID )AS AvlAssets ,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition by AssetTypeID Order by AssetTypeID ) AS Seq
FROM AssetStatus 
)Dt
WHERE Dt.Seq=1
```

Comment: dear sir thank you so much for a your effort in helping me. to be very honest I am not able to understand your query since I am a newbie and it looks advanced.  SELECT COUNT(IsAssetIssued) AS AvlAssets 
FROM AssetStatus WHERE (AssetTypeID = 1). I want to modify it so that i will get available balance by counting true or false values from the IsAssetIssued column based on dynamic AssetTypeID values which i am providing from an asp.net page

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help you people helped me log. There was only a slight change in the query i.e. i put the IsAssetIssued value fixed to false and set the AssetTypeID to be dynamic.

SELECT COUNT(IsAssetIssued) AS AvlAssets FROM AssetStatus WHERE (IsAssetIssued = 'False') AND (AssetTypeID = 1);

it it worked perfectly.